# Rails - page is not loading after submitting form through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form in which i am using ajax validation, for that i have made the form as :remote => true and the view is given as

```
<%= nested_form_for @interview_round, :remote => true do |f| %>
   <div id="error-div"> </div>
<%= f.text_field :interviewer_name %>
<%= f.text_field :log_skill, :id=>'hint-log' %>
<%= f.text_field :comm_skill, :id=>'hint-comm' %>
<%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

and the controller is given as

```
  def update
    @interview_round = InterviewRound.where(id: params[:id]).first
    respond_to do |format|
     if  @interview_round.update_attributes round_params

        format.html{ redirect_to interview_path(@interview_round.interview_id), notice: I18n.t('round_created')}
        format.js
     else
       format.html { render :action => "edit" }
       format.js
     end
      end
  end
```

i am showing the errors in the update.js.erb

```
<% if @interview_round.errors.present?%>
$('#error-div').html('<%= j(render 'shared/error_messages', :target => @interview_round) %>');
<% else %>
$('form.edit_interview_round').removeAttr('data-remote')
<% end %>
```

Now when i am submitting form the errors are coming remotely through ajax and showing on the page but when i am submitting the form without any error the page is not redirecting to the desired page but it is storing the data in database and submitting the form , though i am also trying to remove the data-remote on the form when there are no error it is removing in the HTML  but still the page is not loading when i submit

Please Help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use remote: true you can't redirect via the 'redirect' function as it's a 'script' request and doesn't create a new page/headers etc.

The following would work for example, the syntax is ugly but this will redirect:

```
format.html{ redirect_to interview_path(@interview_round.interview_id), notice: I18n.t('round_created')}
format.js { render js: "window.location.href = '#{interview_path(@interview_round.interview_id)}'" }
```

However you would be better off doing the JS code within a seperate .js view file for the action. If you create a view file in the same directory as your HTML view called update.js, with the javascript re-direct in there, you could then remove the line I gave you altogether and keep view related code where it belongs, in the views.

To do that, you would create a file 'update.js.erb' in app/views/{controllername}/update.js.erb with this:

```
<% if @interview_round.errors.present?%>
  $('#error-div').html('<%= j(render 'shared/error_messages', :target => @interview_round) %>');
<% else %>
  window.location.href = '<%= interview_path(@interview_round.interview_id) %>';
<% end %>
```

Then revert the controller action back to:

```
format.html{ redirect_to interview_path(@interview_round.interview_id), notice: I18n.t('round_created')}
format.js {}
```

The JS file will be rendered automatically, cleaning up the controller.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct ? i am putting this in my controller but getting syntax error

Comment: worked !! though not clean as you said :P , but still thankx :)

Comment: Cool. Try my extended suggestion, create an update.js.erb file in app/views/<controllername>/ with that JS line of code in it. Then revert back to the initial 'format.js' line in your controller action and it should render that file automatically.

Comment: i already have the update.js.erb  see in my question , what i need to write in it ? please tell

Comment: I updated my answer with the code needed for the cleaner approach.

Comment: Actually wait, I missed something in your question

Comment: no it's not redirecting , i am on the same page and the url changed to   http://localhost:3000/interviews/3#{interview_path(@interview_round.interview_id)}

Comment: Fixed, sorry I'm doing 10 things at once :)

Comment: worked , thank you so much for giving your time !! :)

Comment: I'm pleased it's working now. I should read questions more, as you already had the update.js.erb file it was a 2 line answer but hey ho!

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` part in update.js.erb, you are not redirecting the user to a different location, so whenever there are no errors in your form, your url will remain same, and you will not be redirected.